# Eclipse WindowBuilder (windows 7)

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I got problem with WindowBuilder in eclipse. It keeps telling me that :
"Unknown GUI toolkit" or "Eclipse is running under 1.7, but this Java project has a 1.8".
I've got installed jdk/jre 1.8, i've been trying solutions from different forum threads, i've been installing different patches, plugins, setting preferences but still the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Add some details ... for example, what do you have in Window > Preferences: Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables; Java > Installed JREs ... what is the version of your Eclipse? (Mars, Luna, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Mars, Installed Jres - jdk 1.8.0 and jre 1.8.0

[This is what i got in classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE6K9.jpg)